# Building a simple OPT forum

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I am trying to building a simple OPT forum which I have build but now I want to add reverse functionality for example when user press backspace input should focus on previous element.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input input')

inputs.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.dataset.index = i;
    e.addEventListener("input", () => {
        if (e.value.length >= 1) {
            if (e.dataset.index >= i && inputs.length - 1 > i) {
                e.nextElementSibling.focus();
            }
        } else {
            if (inputs.length - 1 > i || e.dataset.index < inputs.length) {
                e.previousElementSibling.focus();
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to detect the press of the backspace key.

It looks like you want each input to take exactly one character. In that case I would suggest that you keep the current character selected, and to make arrow keys also move the focus.

Don't name the `input` element `e`, as `e` is usually used as name for the event object -- just to avoid confusion for someone reading your code.

Here is one way to do it:

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input input')];

inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
    const previous = () => inputs[i-1]?.focus?.();
    const next = () => inputs[i+1]?.focus?.();
    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
        if (input.value.length > 1) input.value = input.value[0];
        if (input.value.length) next();
    });
    input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key == "ArrowRight") next();
        if (e.key == "ArrowLeft") previous();
    });
    input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        if (e.key == "Backspace") {
            previous();
            e.preventDefault();
        } 
    });
});
inputs[0].focus();

// Ensure that current input has its content selected
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => {
    const input = document.activeElement;
    if (inputs.includes(input)) input.setSelectionRange(0, 1);
});
```

```css
.input input { width: 1em }
```

```html
<div class="input">
<input><input><input><input><input>
</div>
```